# Drop/Intercept Calls

Tags: android, telephony

As part of my application I need to block incoming calls. I.e While my application is running, I will drop any call and simply notify the caller that the user is busy or something similar.

I wish to do this using the android SDK, I hope to support Android versions 2.2 and above.

I've already looked at

[How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android)
(Says, and I quote "It is Mission Impossible for the time being.")

[Intercept incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141494/intercept-incoming-calls)
(Also says not possible)

[Can we intercept incoming call in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222295/can-we-intercept-incoming-call-in-android)
(Gives `telephonyService.endCall();` as the solution)

[Create a custom call handling Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257242/create-a-custom-call-handling-application)
(Says it's not possible)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/gc5vOHjBE30
(discussion seemed inconclusive)

But they don't seem to be of much help.
Even after reading of a lot of questions on stack overflow, google groups and other forums I am still not clear as to whether this is possible or not. Also a lot of the questions and threads are over 2-3 years old, thus adding to my confusion.

And if this is possible then what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible after android 2.2 which dropped the hidden itelephony interface.

So yes "It is Mission Impossible for the time being."