# Can you block incoming traffic with an Android app?

Tags: android, mobile, sms, call

Is it posible that Android would allow an app to block a phone call, email and or SMS from coming through to the device?

e.g. User opens app and sets it to block all incoming info for 2 hours. App blocks all email, SMS and calls for 2 hours.

Comment: Did you search for existing questions?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android  for example.

Comment: Thanks, I did look around, and found a bunch of similar questions on filtering calls, which seemed to be not possible.. Was wondering whether it would be possible to set some setting in Android using an app, which just blocked off incoming traffic altogether.

Now looking into the answer dropped in by Macarse below.

Answer (score 1):

If it just for some time I would try to turn `Airplane mode on`.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on) question.

Comment: Thanks Macarse.. I'm checking into the link you provided, and in seems to be somewhat of an ongoing discussion as to whether turning the airplane mode on/off programmatically really does work out well. Would you happen to know if its definitely possible or not?

Comment: Not really. But that's definitely what I would try first.