# How to set the AIRPLANE_MODE_ON to "True" or ON?

Tags: android

I am planning to drop a call and I find this as one of workaround for that. 
How do I activate the airplane mode via code?

This way I will drop the call based on some event.

Comment: Please note that toggling airplane mode on/off is no longer possible as of Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean major release 1). This is because Google has adopted a BANDAGE solution to address shortcomings in Android instead of re-examining its security model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the blog article *[Android: Controlling Airplane Mode](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html)* ,

Works only upto **API 16**

```
// Toggle airplane mode.
Settings.System.putInt(
      context.getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where `isEnabled` is whether airplane mode is enabled or not.

Comment: I was not able to deploy it. Does this code go in Broadcastreceiver class

Comment: It goes wherever you need it to to perform the action. Don't forget you need the WRITE_SETTINGS permission to do this, though.

Comment: I am still getting errors like  Settings.System cannot be   resolved

Comment: Keep in mind that you need: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />` in your manifest.xml for this to work.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do that on 4.2 and above ? I can't find a way yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that this is no longer possible starting from Android 4.2 and above.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static boolean getAirplaneMode(Context context) {
      try {
      int airplaneModeSetting = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);
      return airplaneModeSetting==1?true:false;
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
        int mode = isEnable ? 1 : 0;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global airplane_mode_on "+mode);
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", isEnable);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

shell uid can change airplane_mode_on ,but send ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED need permission (need to be system uid)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```