# turn off airplane mode in Android

Tags: android, mode, airplane-mode

I would like to turn off the airplane mode if num>50, I implemented this code (from [Toggle airplane mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android)) but when executed I get a force close, can any one help here?

```
                if(num>50){
                    // read the airplane mode setting
                    boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                          getContentResolver(), 
                          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

                    // toggle airplane mode
                    Settings.System.putInt(
                          getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

                    // Post an intent to reload
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);



                }
```

o.k. I implemented the premonitions but i would like to change the if statement:

```
if num>=50 and airplane mode=on toggle it off 
if  airplane mode=off and num<50 toggle it on
```

Can some one help me writing the new code? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: be cool and accept answers to your questions that helped you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You most likely did not add `WRITE_SETTING` permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

---

Also note that code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
 intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Is not supposed to work, because according to documentation on [`ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED):

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

And even though you can currently send this broadcast without System permissions, it may change in future releases of Android.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to have set permissions for toggling airplane mode in your android manifest.

Take a look here [Toggle airplane mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Refer following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service state changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                boolean isEnabled = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
            /*   setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                Intent intent_mode = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
               intent_mode.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent_mode);*/

                if(isEnabled==true)
                { setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flight mode on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                    newIntent.putExtra("state", false);
                    sendBroadcast(newIntent);
                }
                else
                { setSettings(context, isEnabled?1:0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flight mode off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void setSettings(Context context, int value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                Settings.System.putInt(
                          context.getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
            } else {
                Settings.Global.putInt(
                          context.getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
            }       

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        }       
    }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);


}

//permissions needed:
```

//  
  //

Comment: Describe what are the changes you made?

Comment: firstly,use brocast reciever so that it works in background...then have a look over  setSettings() method which is used for version related problems...and     IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE"); is important part...let me know if ur question is answered...