# Programmatically enabling Airplane mode does not disable Mobile date and Bluetooth

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I want to turn on airplane mode through the code and turn off bluetooth, wifi and mobile data.
First, execute this in the console:

```sh
adb shell pm grant com.package.name android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Second, turn on airplane mode from code:

```js
//Set radios cell,wifi,bluetooth witch will be off
Settings.Global.putString(requireContext().contentResolver,
   Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS,
   "${Settings.Global.RADIO_CELL},
   ${Settings.Global.RADIO_WIFI},
   ${Settings.Global.RADIO_BLUETOOTH}"
)

Settings.Global.putInt(
    requireContext().contentResolver,
    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,  1
)
```

But in the settings, I see that only wifi is turned off, bluetooth and mobile date are still on. Why can't I turn them all off from the code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some android manifactures require usage of *Settings.Secure* instead of *Settings.Global*. Check it via command

```
adb shell settings list global
```

Second of all, you should try to notify system about your changes.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

There is parameter for this intent that is unneccessary to use on almost every device to notify specific airplane state (1 - ON, 0 - OFF):

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state <state>
```

Comment: Of course, you can do it programmatically with Intent.

Comment: I can't do it from code because I am getting java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=27135, uid=10138. This happens because WRITE_SETTINGS system permissions (available only for system apps) are needed. Similar problem on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22349928/16343477

Comment: But you somehow managed to get WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission. Then I suppose it's possible to get a little more:)

Comment: WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS can be granted via adb (see command in description), but it is not working for WRITE_SETTINGS permission. I am getting: Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS requested by com.physiq.monitor.mdm.watch is not a changeable permission type

Comment: Then it's root-only feature, okay, that's unfortunate. I've seen some OEMs that can change airplane mode without intent. If you are still searching, there is no workaround with kiosk apps or DeviceOwner|ProfileOwner