# How to Enable/Disable flight mode in android?

Tags: android

I am writing an android app, which needs to disable cell signals of the phone for a specific time period and need to enable the signal back. Can someone pls help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Hi, Thanks for the below answers, this is working for the virtual device. But this doesn't work for the real device(Samsung Galaxy y) :( , pls someone can tell , why is that?

Comment: Duplicate of many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android <- Should have what you're looking for

Comment: What's the error on Samsung Galaxy Y when you run this code? Are you getting an exception? Can you share the logcat output?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
        context = getApplicationContext();
    if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked()){
        boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
        if(isEnabled == false)
        {
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", 1);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }



        }else
        {

            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", 0);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

};
});
```

In the else part of the code change the number one to number 0.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, this is working for the virtual device. But this doesn't work for the real device(Samsung Galaxy y)  :(  , pls someone can tell , why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page here

http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html

// Toggle airplane mode.

```
  Settings.System.putInt(
      context.getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
```

// Post an intent to reload.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
where isEnabled is whether airplane mode is enabled or not.
```