# Active bluetooth on airplane mode

Tags: android

I need to turn off the gsm network at my application but enable bluetooth.
I know how to change to airplane mode [Toggle airplane mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android), but is there a way to keep the bluetooth on (I know that them both working on radio signals), I think it's possible on android 4 cause I saw some application that doing it like "Auto Airplane".

I've tried the code below with no help:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", 1);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

thank's,
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission
It's working, but the Bluethooth section is disabled from the phone settings, the phone is visible to other devics.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be possible since airplane mode is design to cut down every signal, which TMHO should includes Bluetooth.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_mode