# How to set the Permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS in android?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to enable the Accessibility Service Settings above 4.0 but It is showing an Exception i.e.,

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

In Manifest I have Declared This permission like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

But in manifest giving compilation Error i.e., Permission is only System Apps.
So i am not Understanding how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Here is my sample code

```
if (Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED).contains("1")) {
            if (Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED).contains("1")) {
                System.out.println("Putting the Value to Enable..");
                Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, 0);
            } else {
                Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.TOUCH_EXPLORATION_ENABLED, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The best solution for this is, simply go to developer option and turn on the option disable permission monitoring, so now if you will try to change your android device screen size using cmd, it will not throw any error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not available to applications. No app outside of the system/firmware can get that permisssion.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045283/write-secure-settings-permission-error-even-when-added-in-manifest) answer

Comment: Strange. Tasker seems to require this permission to execute its "Airplane Mode" task actions.