# How i get android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Tags: android

Here is my class that extends from Thread. I use it for running Shell command:

```
class ShellCommand extends Thread {

        ShellCommand(MainActivity activity) {}

        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Shell.SU.run("pm grant packagename android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS");
        }
}


locald.start();

if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS") == 0)
{
    //I want to do something if permission granted. But it says permission denied
}
```

Comment: Problem solved with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app

Answer (score 0):

first you should know that permission **WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS** is not available to andriod apps!

[You could get more info by the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045283/write-secure-settings-permission-error-even-when-added-in-manifest)

Comment: I want this using libsuperuser on rooted device

Comment: If you want use that permission, please build your app in android source code project, put you app project to directory package.apps.YourAppProject

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking.
In the list find an entry with ID = ProtectedPermission. Set the Severity to something lower than Error. This way you can still compile the project using Eclipse.

In Android Studio:

File -> Settings -> Inspections
Under Android Lint, locate Using system app permission. Either uncheck the checkbox or choose a Severity lower than Error.