# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Tags: java, android

This is my code by which i am building airplan mode On/OFF on Platform 5.0.0
below is mine Activity.java source code please  suggest the changes which i need to do in manifeast.xml for access the permission.

```
package com.rjil.airplanemodeonoff;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // constants
    static final String STATUS_ON = "Airplane Mode: ON";
    static final String STATUS_OFF = "Airplane Mode: OFF";

    static final String TURN_ON = "Turn ON";
    static final String TURN_OFF = "Turn OFF";

    // controls
    TextView TVAirplaneMode;
    ToggleButton tBAirplane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // load controls
        TVAirplaneMode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVAirplaneMode);
        tBAirplane = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tBAirplane);
        // update UI at first time loading
        updateUI(isAirplaneMode());
        // set click event for button
        tBAirplane.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // check current state first
                boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
                // toggle the state
                if (state) toggleAirplaneMode(0, state);
                else toggleAirplaneMode(1, state);
                // update UI to new state
                updateUI(!state);
            }
        });
    }
    public void toggleAirplaneMode(int value, boolean state) {
        // toggle airplane mode
        //check the version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //if less than verson 4.2
            Settings.System.putInt(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
        } else {
            Settings.Global.putInt(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
        }
        // broadcast an intent to inform
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", !state);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void updateUI(boolean state) {
        //set text according to state
        if(state) {
            TVAirplaneMode.setText(STATUS_ON);
            tBAirplane.setText(TURN_OFF);
        } else {
            TVAirplaneMode.setText(STATUS_OFF);
            tBAirplane.setText(TURN_ON);
        }
    }


    public boolean isAirplaneMode() {
        //check the version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {//if less than verson 4.2
            return Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: can u please share your manifest code .

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: If you found any security exception in further it may help to find your missing things, and you must need to know about why we need to keep permission  declaration in manifest.

Their is another case for occurring this kind of exceptions check here once: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13045283/2983864

Answer (score 5):

WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not for use by third-party applications. No app outside of the system/firmware can get that permission regardless whether you are on rooted or production builds.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045283/write-secure-settings-permission-error-even-when-added-in-manifest) answer