# Redial multiple phone numbers android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am in he middle of makinga custom dialer application. The application needs to dial different phone numbers within 5-10 seconds. The code pretty much looks like this but I need to call multiple numbers from an Array of Numbers. I need to force close a call activity to start another call activity.

```
private void quickDial(String[] numbers) {

   /*
    * LOOP with CountDownTimer code
    *
   */ 
   Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + number[i]);
   Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
   startActivity(dial);

}
```

Do you have any solution? Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) to listen the phone state change. when detecting the phone call ended, start another dial activity.

Comment: But how to force close the call activity? The current call should be automatically closed after 5 seconds to start the next call.

Comment: the best solution is to turn phone to airplane mode to end the call [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android)