# How to on/off airplane mode programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying  to programmatically on/off the airplane mode in android, I rooted my device even install app as a system app but still troubling to achieve. below is my code

```
 public void toggleAirplaneMode(int value, boolean state) {
        Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, value);
        // broadcast an intent to inform
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        intent.putExtra("state", !state);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

calling the function by for turn off the airplane mode 
   toggleAirplaneMode(0,true);
```

calling the function by for turn on the airplane mode 
       toggleAirplaneMode(1,false);

it's throw exception
permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.write_secure_settings

I Already rooted the device and installed the app as a system app
   in my manifest permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This question is already asked here, [Turn ON-OFF airplane mode in any api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762773/9528882)

Answer (score 0):

did you ask for superuser permission

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

before running your code?

Comment: right now i am not added above code

Comment: but to use root features u need to get permission and its done using the code i mentioned