# How to enable flight mode with root android 7?

Tags: android

Interested in such a question. Everywhere I read that on android 7 it is programmatically impossible to turn off flight mode. And they write that if there is a root, then everything can be done. And I see that there are programs that allow you to programmatically enable flight mode (Tasker for example).

Question
How the root helps turn on flight mode. Do we have access to new features? Or there is editing files (adding scripts). Describe in the general process, if possible, at least a general idea.

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785146/5463706

Answer (score 0):

With root, you get access to modify system files. It is usually due to this that many apps do not work if you have a root. Generally speaking, when you have the ability to modify these system files, you or any other app can make any change to your device.

I really suggest that you go visit [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/). You will find a massive community that is super interested with this kind of stuff. The community there is very well versed with rooting and custom ROMs which I believe you may find interesting based on your question.