# how to block or engage lines completely on android programmatically?

Tags: android

In my present application which i am developing i need to engage phone lines completely till  my application is running(i.e. i should not receive any call or sms and i myself shouldn't be  able to call or send sms) and as soon as my application exits the service should be     returned suggest me a way to do this thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why you want to take control away from the user like this?

Comment: This particular application is for the user. When this application is being used by the user, he shouldn't be disturbed by anything.. that is the reason i want a way to do this. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your action can please the user of your application.

If you want to block all calls/sms, may be try moving the phone into Airplane mode. After completing your action bring it back from Airplane mode. Look here [How to set the AIRPLANE_MODE_ON to "True" or ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on) for how to toggle the Airplane mode.

Comment: Through AIRPLANE MODE the whole of gsm circuitry is set off but in my application i need to use the internet through my application which is not possible through AIRPLANE mode...indirectly i can sum up that the telephony channel should be closed and the data channel (for internet)must be working. Hope you now understand what i really want is there a way to do it any one please help!

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure if you can do that in Android.