# Enable and Disable Airplane Mode successively Android

Tags: android, android-intent, airplane-mode

I am just a starter in Android. I have an Android code which has a Button. On click of the button, it should Invoke AirPlane mode and then again back to normal mode. Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // load controls
    tvStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    togState = (Button)findViewById(R.id.togState);

    // set click event for button
    togState.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                     
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // check current state first
                            boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
                            // toggle the state
                            toggleAirplaneMode(state);

                            state = isAirplaneMode();
                            // toggle the state
                            toggleAirplaneMode(state);

                    }
            });
}

public void toggleAirplaneMode(boolean state) {
    // toggle airplane mode
    Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);

    // broadcast an intent to inform
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra("state", !state);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}



public boolean isAirplaneMode() {
    return Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
}
```

}

The problem here is, my phone will go in AirPlane mode and it toggles back also. But this process I cannot stop. Is the problem with the way I handled the OnClick Listener by calling same method (toggleAirplaneMode) twice?

Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it finally

I used this in my code

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // check current state first
                boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
                // toggle the state
                toggleAirplaneMode(state);

               state = isAirplaneMode();
                // toggle the state
                toggleAirplaneMode(state);
                ser = new ServiceState();
                ser.setState(STATE_IN_SERVICE);
               }
```

And I have declared final int STATE_IN_SERVICE = 0; before OnCreate. And ser is the instance of ServiceState.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: originally it can not on-off the airplane mode, it just off sim card but after click on that again sim card can notbe visible whts the solutions ??

Comment: Hi nikiIgeniusDev. I am posting my entire code below. Chk out.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on) contains code necessary to do this. Also make sure you have the WRITE_SETTINGS permission.

Adapted from [Controlling Airplane Mode:](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.in/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html)

```
// read the airplane mode setting
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
      getContentResolver(), 
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(
      getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks ajent451. I also referred from the same links. But i want two successive toggles in a single button click.

Comment: I found out the solution and it worked. Have answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `onClick` method with this:

```
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        // check current state first
                        boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
                        // toggle the state
                        final Handler handler = new Handler(){
                            @Override
                            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                toggleAirplaneMode(!state);
                                super.handleMessage(msg);
                            }       
                        };
                        Thread th = new Thread() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                              toggleAirplaneMode(!state);
                              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                           };
                        };
                        th.start();
                }
```

Every time you will click the button, it will toggle the airplaneMode.
If it doesn't work, try removing `!`

Comment: Will it Invoke Flight Mode and then Invoke Normal Mode on a Single Click of a Button?

Comment: I mean I want to click only once. I need to invoke Flight mode then back to normal mode by clicking the button only once. The code in Answer one goes to flight mode on click of a button but how to go back to normal mode?

Comment: on first click, it will go to flight mode.
on second click, it will go to normal mode.

Comment: Do you want to do both the things simultaneously on a single click?

Comment: Yes @micro.pravi.. Simultaneously.. First it should toggle to airplane mode then back to normal mode. I want to avoid two clicks.

Comment: I am trying @micro.pravi

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it in my cell. It is going into flight mode. Then it is coming to No Service State. (The broken Memory Card like symbol appearing instead of Signal Bars)

Comment: I have declared handler before OnCreate. Since i was getting an error stating :
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); //Local variable handler might not be initialised
super.handleMessage(msg);

Comment: try removing super.handleMessage(msg) @trueblue

Comment: Same issue after removing super.handleMessage(msg)

Comment: Thanks micro.pravi for your help. I found out the solution and it worked. Have answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out... This might help..

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

```
private void changeRadioComponentEnabled(Context paramContext, String paramString, boolean paramBoolean1, boolean paramBoolean2)
  {
    boolean bool = false;
    ContentResolver localContentResolver = paramContext.getContentResolver();
    int i;
    if (!paramBoolean1)
      i = 1;
    else
      i = 0;
    Settings.System.putInt(localContentResolver, "airplane_mode_on", i);
    Settings.System.putString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_radios", paramString);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
    if (!paramBoolean1)
      bool = true;
    localIntent.putExtra("state", bool);
    paramContext.sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    if (!paramBoolean2)
    {
      if (paramString.indexOf("cell") == 0)
        Settings.System.putString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_radios", "cell");
    }
    else
      Settings.System.putString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_radios", "cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc");
  }




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.context = this;
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
        MainActivity.this.changeRadioComponentEnabled(MainActivity.this.context, "cell", false, false);
      }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
      {
          MainActivity.this.changeRadioComponentEnabled(MainActivity.this.context, "cell", true, false);
      }
    });



}
```