# How to put a phone in Airplane mode programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, audio, application-settings, appsettings, android-audiomanager

Can any one tell me how to put a phone in Airplane mode programmatically with a single click on button in android?

Comment: No Harshit..I want an airplane mode to be On programatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the AIRPLANE\_MODE\_ON to "True" or ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the blog article http://dustinbreese.blogspot.in/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html ,

Works only upto API 16

```
// Toggle airplane mode.
Settings.System.putInt(
      context.getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where isEnabled is whether airplane mode is enabled or not.

Comment: but the app must be "system app"

Answer (score -2):

```
 this code to make phone silent

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

there is also vibrate mode  and normal mode

```
       am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
       am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanks steevoo..I know these things but i want to on an airplane mode via programatically.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2