# How to turn Android's airplane mode on and off programmatically?

Tags: android

How do I turn Android's airplane mode on and off programmatically?

Comment: ... and see also [How to set the AIRPLANE_MODE_ON to “True” or ON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on)

Comment: thanks you're right , I saw too many answer already  and I confused 
and I didn't know what should I do thanks again

Comment: dvnrrs please help me for this error why (System cannot be resolved or is not a field) I got this error