# Toggle on/off the airplane mode for the given network.

Tags: java, android

I have a mobile phone with dual sim. If I want to turn on Airplane mode, its happening for both sim.

Is it possible to do for only one sim (user can select the one of the two) programmatically? I saw the posts over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on), that  they work till API 16. Any other work arounds?

As I can see this in the docs:

> Some device settings defined by Settings.System are now read-only. If
>   your app attempts to write changes to settings defined in
>   Settings.System that have moved to Settings.Global, the write
>   operation will silently fail when running on Android 4.2 and higher.
>   Even if your value for android:targetSdkVersion and
>   android:minSdkVersion is lower than 17, your app is not able to modify
>   the settings that have moved to Settings.Global when running on
>   Android 4.2 and higher.

They say *Settings.System are now read-only*, but reading these blogs,[I don't need your permission!](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/26/i-dont-need-your-permission/), which explains how to skip the permissions part, by this way we can ask the user to give permission to turn on/off the airplane mode and *escape* the permission issue mentioned here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do for only one sim (user can select the one of the two) programmatically? I saw the posts over here, that they work till API 16. Any other work arounds?

There's no official Android API which supports this. Additionally, I'm not aware of any vendor/device specific SDKs which provides such an API.

> They say Settings.System are now read-only, but reading these blogs,I don't need your permission!, which explains how to skip the permissions part, by this way we can ask the user to give permission to turn on/off the airplane mode and escape the permission issue mentioned here?

The example in this blog post has nothing to do with airplane mode.

Edit: Please also note that airplane mode isn't related to the SIM cards but to the connectivity hardware, e.g., Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or cell radio modules. Thus, when enabling airplane mode this hardware is turned off. Depending on the device only one cell radio module might be built-in which would make it impossible to restrict airplane mode to a single SIM card.