# How to keep your mobile on flight mode in android programmatically..without phone root please tell me

Tags: android

Nothing any picture here but plz tell me the answer...define all permission like write_secure, the System.secure, but not any output plz tell sir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android/24785146

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the AIRPLANE\_MODE\_ON to "True" or ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't switch airplane mode programmatically if the device is not rooted.

As written in http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

> Some device settings defined by Settings.System are now read-only. If
>   your app attempts to write changes to settings defined in 
>   Settings.System that have moved to Settings.Global, the write
>   operation will silently fail when running on Android 4.2 and higher.
>   Even if your value for android:targetSdkVersion and 
>   android:minSdkVersion is lower than 17, your app is not able to modify
>   the settings that have moved to Settings.Global when running on
>   Android 4.2 and higher.

This answer was taken from here:

[How to programmatically enable and disable Flight mode on Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766909/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-flight-mode-on-android-4-2)