# How to accept automatically a call in android?

Tags: android

For my project, I need to accept all call. I have searched and tested for now 4 days.
However thanks to http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html and [How to reject incoming call programatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809588/how-to-reject-incoming-call-programatically-in-android) I have maid an apply but it doesn't work; when I emule my apply, I have an error like this "The application has stopped unexpectedlty.Please try again"

Here the link for download my project : http://dl.free.fr/getfile.pl?file=/FM9HlJMZ
(click on "telecharger ce fichier")

Comment: Are we talking Android, iOS, are you working using some Avaya libraries?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm talking about android and I'm using SDK from eclipse (in fact the plugin android)

Comment: I've not done any android work but people will be able to help you better if you provide some code to show where you are and what you have tried.

Comment: You should identify the code where it happen and then discussed it. Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the setContentView() method after extending your class to Activity.

First learn the basics of android (specially lifecycle of an activity) and then try to make an app.

If you don't need any UI there is no need to extend Activity and you can implement other basic component like service.