# Reject Incoming calls in android

Tags: android, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android)

How can we reject incoming phone call in android if the incoming number is already stored in phonebook.

What method is used to reject incoming calls? I know how to detect incoming calls but don't know how to reject.

Comment: I really hope this isn't possible

Comment: how to find duplicate block number           ?