# How I block incoming call?

Tags: android, callblocking

I have read [How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android), but IDE doesn't know how to resolve com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony. The internal API has gone?
How I can access setting->call setting->auto reject call?

Comment: If you search Stackoverflow, this question is asked many, many times.

Answer (score 0):

com.android.internal.* is internal , you can't access with SDK in eclipse.

Comment: How to get please give the code below then that can be useful for other developers