# Watching for phone interactions

Tags: android

I'm writing a logging API that I'll deploy with an android application. It will ideally look to see when the phone is used and which number / contact the phone operator is contacting or receiving a phone call from.

I was wondering can anyone point me to which libraries I'd need to use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For incoming calls: last known information is that you can see them, but can't interfere. See [How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android).

For outgoing calls: you can intercept the intent and act or it or just observe and pass it on. See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/931e04811839326e.

Comment: I don't want to interfere with the call , really I just want to log it. Both incoming and outgoing, I'll give the links a gander.