# How to Reject a call programatically in android

Tags: android, telephony, callblocking

In my app I will maintain a list of contacts.

Any calls from contacts in the list will be dropped.  They will show under missed calls but the phone will not ring.

Comment: ContentObserver is word where your can best practice

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to block calls in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android)

Comment: `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` [permission is for system apps only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread) (for android 2.3 and above). If you want to use app only for phone you have access to, you can [make your app system app](http://projectmaxs.org/documentation/systemapp.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First create this Interface:

```
  public interface ITelephony {

        boolean endCall();

        void answerRingingCall();

        void silenceRinger();

  }
```

Then Create this class that extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    private String blacklistednumber = "+458664455";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       try {
         Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
         Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
         m.setAccessible(true);
         ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
         Log.e("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
         if ((phoneNumber != null) && phoneNumber.equals(blacklistednumber)) { 
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
            Log.e("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
         }

       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

This will only block that single phonenumber, but you get the point.

In your manifest add this:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
```

Comment: hi i did that. But notihing happened. How to create that interface what i mean normal interface or aidl file

Comment: just create a normal intercafe. But you might need to place it in a package called: com.android.internal.telephony try that.

Comment: even it is not working i think we have to generate aidl file. But do not know how to do that.

Comment: No you dont have to do that. This works just fine for me. 
Make sure the phonenumber you want to block is the same as the one that is incoming. You can check it in LogCat under.

Comment: hi Larsen its working i checked now. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: getting NoSuchMethodException at Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");.. How to avoid it????

Comment: How would you add the "android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" permission?

Comment: @insomniac please use this <uses-permission tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: Any idea how to achieve it on android oreo , I tested the above code that works before oreo but not on android oreo. Please share what is needed to change.Thanks

Comment: Permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is only granted to system apps

Comment: this code 6.0 work perfect but 7.0 or above not work so any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Download the class of ITelephony from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java#ITelephony.Stub.Proxy.getDataState%28%29).

Then put it in a package (make a new package) of `com.android.internal.telephony.`
Then import the package to the appropriate class and for rejecting a call use the `endCall()` method