# reject call in android

Tags: android

i tried to implement the code here:

[How to Reject a call programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347871/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-in-android)

however it doesnt work on android 2.3+

is there any way to reject calls in android 2.3+?

Comment: can you help me how to do it?can you post the code for this?thanks

Comment: also,is there any way to silence the ringtone when i recieve a call? i didnt find how to implement it on android 2.3+?

Comment: i want to make an app that when i press a button he will reject all the calls with spesific numbers...i want to know how can i do it?

Comment: elso i want to know how can i silence the ringtone when i recieve a call from someone in android 2.3+? no one here can guide me please?