# Rejecting Incoming call in android

Tags: android, telephony, callblocking, incoming-call

I want to reject incoming in android, I have seen so many code from these links.

1. [Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)
2. [How to Reject a call programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347871/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-in-android)
3. http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html
4. http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html?showComment=1361478035090#c5468022990217431781

But I am still unable to do it, can anybody tell me in simple and easy steps how to do it?

Comment: I intercepted outgoing call, but unable to understand the logic behind incoming calls and their interceptions mentioned on these pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [End call in android programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 17):

In order to intercept your call you just have to:
1. Make a package named. com.android.internal.telephony;
2. In this package make a interface file named ITelephony.
and write this code in that interface file.

```
boolean endCall();
void answerRingingCall();
void silenceRinger();
```

Now in your class where you want to intercept the call extend that class to `BroadcastReceiver` and in `onReceive()`function write the following code.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   try {
     Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
     Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
     m.setAccessible(true);
     telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
     Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
     if ((phoneNumber != null)) { 
        telephonyService.endCall();
        Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
     }

   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Thats it.

Comment: Worked for me . Awesome !!

Comment: getting NoSuchMethodException at Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");.. How to avoid it????

Comment: @Zubair is there any permission needed for doing this?

Comment: its not working. Is there any updated method to block calls in android programmatically?

Comment: This did work but with latest security path (H2 2018) it seems this method has been plugged by Google. At least that seems to be the case on my Pixel 2, not sure if anybody else can confirm

Comment: did not work through error :java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getITelephony []

Answer (score 5):

Provide appropriate permission and add the `ITelephony.java` file

```
private void declinePhone(Context context) throws Exception {

        try {

            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
            serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("unable", "msg cant dissconect call....");

        }
```

Comment: Great solutions .. Need to put one add on to it ... For M+ versions we are also required to take run time permission for CALL_PHONE. Cheers!

Comment: Have put the complete solution over self asked question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527748/programmatically-disconnect-call-in-android-marshmallow-version

Answer (score 2):

You will be needing a broadcast receiver for that with an intent filter I think ACTION_ANSWER

more details about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER

You can register it using the manifest file or the method registerReceiver

more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)

Also you need to specify appropriate permissions in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
```

The links you have provided are quite good. You just need more patience :)

happy coding.

Comment: lol..I have been trying for 4 to 5 days..thought may there be something that is missed in these links..

Comment: Another tip, if you want the phone calls will be rejected only if the app is running, better register the receiver programmatically in onResume cycle and unregister it onPause cycle. Because I think if you will register it on the manifest it is registered as long as the app is not removed in your system, and it will capture or receive phone calls even the app is not running.

Comment: Hmm. that's good point. But what if I am using services? I should unregister it on destroy()?

Comment: You cannot unregister services, call stopService method instead and do it onPause() cycle because I think onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called by the system.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface in `com.android.internal.telephony`
and name as

```
interface ITelephony {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
            double aDouble, String aString);
    boolean endCall();
    void silenceRinger();strong text
    void answerRingingCall();
}

//   then catch the incoming call intent and call below method



  if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) != null) {
                        number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "INCOMING call catched: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
disconnectPhoneItelephony(mContext)
                    }


    private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context) {
            ITelephony telephonyService;
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                SessionManager.getInstance(context).setBlockStatusAllow("BLOCKED");
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Add necessary permission in Manifest

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tutorial to block all incoming calls you can customize it to block incoming call of only selected numbers.

[Android Incoming Call Block](http://droidcodesnippets.blogspot.com/2012/08/block-all-calls.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build a kiosk app then i suggest you to obtain notification settings and put device to Do not Disturb mode ON.

```
var mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)
```