# Programmatically disconnect call in android Marshmallow version

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to disconnect call through code in upper version of android.

As per document we are not authorized to do so as it is private.

While searching over SO I found different solutions that is working till lollipop.

Inline is what approach I have tried till now.

**Approach One :**

```
public void disconnectCall(String type){
        try {
            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                    serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

            // Reject call and send SMS
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("reject")) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(_incomingNumber, null, "Hey! I am driving right now. Please call me back after some time", null, null);
                Toast.makeText(context, "CALL REJECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Approach Two :**

```
public boolean killCall(Context context) {
        try {
            // Get the boring old TelephonyManager
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            // Get the getITelephony() method
            Class classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

            // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
            methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

            // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
            Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

            // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
            Class telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
            Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

            // Invoke endCall()
            methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

        } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Approach Three :**

```
public void endCall(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm);

            c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName());
            m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(telephonyService);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Above mentioned Approach one is working .. I just out to add run time permission for CALL_PHONE for M+ versions of android.

Follow inline mentions:

**Define Permission in Android Manifest file.**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

**Now get runtime permission for M+ version of android.**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_ACCESS_CALL_PHONE);
            }
            else
            {
                // Proceed as we already have permission.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Proceed as we need not get the permission
        }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_ACCESS_CALL_PHONE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All good!

                    //Toast.makeText(context, "All Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    finish();
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Need call phone permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

**Now use inline method to disconnect call pro-grammatically.**

```
private void declinePhone(Context context) throws Exception {

        try {

            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
            serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("unable", "msg cant dissconect call....");

        }
```

That's it! You are good to go.

Cheers!

Comment: @ErichGarcía Hey! Where should I add this declinePhone(Context context)?

Comment: Use it in your Broadcast Receiver, do some custom actions like save the number in DB, or something else, and later call it.

Comment: Thank you!!! Was the ONLY answer I found that didn't freeze the entire app! Btw, works too on Lollipop, but I'm not sure if the app needs to be a system app or not (my app is and has root permissions too). But it's working!