# Prevent phone incoming calls interrupting SIP calls

Tags: javascript, android, sip, whatsapp, plivo

I am building an application using PLivo API for SIP voice calls. But when there is an incoming phone call, even if the user rejects the call, the SIP call gets interrupted.

Is there any way to prevent this using javascript

Comment: Have you tried this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012082/rejecting-incoming-call-in-android

Comment: I don't think you can prevent this on IOS but I think you can on Android, sorry though, don't know how.