# how to reject call in android programmatically version 9....????/

Tags: android

i have tried so many things but didn't get the solution

```
public void onReject() {
        try {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Method declaredMethod = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony", new Class[0]);
            declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
            Object invoke = declaredMethod.invoke(telephonyManager, new Object[0]);
            Class.forName(invoke.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredMethod("endCall", new Class[0]).invoke(invoke, new Object[0]);
        } catch (Exception unused) {
        }
        stopScreen();



    }

    public void stopScreen() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException unused) {
                }
                IncomingActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).start();
    }


    private void rejectCall(Context context)
    {
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rejecting Incoming call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012082/rejecting-incoming-call-in-android)

Comment: For pie, you have to use Telecom Manager instead of telephony manager

Comment: if it helped you upvote it