# how to reject a call in Android?

Tags: kotlin, call

I need to automatically reject calls from the list of numbers I have set

> I found one solution but it doesn't work

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    private String blacklistednumber = "+458664455";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       try {
         Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
         Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
         m.setAccessible(true);
         ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
         Log.e("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
         if ((phoneNumber != null) && phoneNumber.equals(blacklistednumber)) { 
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
            Log.e("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
         }
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Reject a call programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347871/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-in-android)

Comment: Why it doesn't work? What does not happens? What happens?

Comment: I don't understand how to initialize context and intent in broadcast

Comment: val bundle: Bundle = intent.getExtras()  and  val tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)

Comment: When a call comes in, it won't reject.

Comment: A resource failed to call close.