# Android - offer the user the option to blacklist a number?

Tags: android, telephony, blacklist

I was wondering if anyone knows if its possible to offer the user the possibility to black list a number in Android?

My app works with phone numbers and I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically add a number to the blacklist?

Or if it's possible to send an intent to show the "Add to blacklist" settings screen to the user with the number field populated with the number so that the user can then decide to add the number to the blacklist or not?

Comment: are you looking for this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android

Comment: Not quite , I don't want to block the number myself, I want to allow the user add a number to the black list or automatically pop the black list settings thats on the device.