# How to update call log in android

Tags: android, overriding, contacts, addition

I am new to android, I am creating call blocking application. Here I have written a code which is able to update call log in Emulater but the same code is not working in samsung mobile  v2.2 and in others android.

here is my code:

```
        public  int changeCallLog(String Pnum, Context ct)
     {
  long Phonenumber=Long.parseLong(Pnum);

   int k=0;
    try
    {

     Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
        //Log.d("query 1", "Working , number going to update  =>"+Phonenumber);
      Cursor c = ct.getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, "number="+Phonenumber, null, null); 
      c.moveToFirst();
      //Log.d("query 2", "manage Cursor size="+c.getCount());
      if(c.getCount()>0)
      {
       ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
       //values.put("name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.CACHED_NAME))+"(X)");
       values.put("number", c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER))+" (X)");
       k=ct.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),values,"number="+Phonenumber,null);
         Log.d("Query 3", "k="+k+", Name="+values);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     Toast.makeText(ct, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.d("ResultActivitForCall", "Exception="+e);
    }
  return k;
 }
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Can you explain your question in more deeply?

Comment: check out this link..
this will defenitly help you....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android

Comment: I just want to update call log whenever a call comes app should show number followed by '(X)' in call log.