# How to "control" a call in android?

Tags: java, android

im developing an app where one should be able to call and "reject" a call from the desktop using a small socket program to communicate with the phone over USB.

I got most of it in place, I can call a number from my desktop application, however, when a call is being made it is not under control of the application.

I run a service which starts a server socket thread, and then I bind the local listen port to my computer with `adb forward tcp`. When I send a `CALL:123123` it will start a new call intent that calls the number "123123".

How would I go about making a call and then at some point ending it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this is not possible to do programatically. Android doesn't let programs make manipulate phone calls without some user interaction due to security concerns.

Comment: I did get it working by using the method mentioned in this post:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android