# Launch Android app rather than system's default phone app

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, mobile-application, android-launcher

I made an Android app to show an attractive GUI whenever there is a new outgoing or incoming call. Whenever a broadcast signal (either `NEW_OTUGOING_CALL` or `PHONE_STATE`) is received, my app launches, same as the Android mobile's default phone app.

Sometimes my app appears on screen and sometimes the default phone app appears on screen. Only my app should be launched to handle incoming/outgoing calls or my app should be on top of default phone app.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android. See the first answer. I think you are out of luck on this one.

Comment: There must be some way to be sure to see my app in foreground instead of PHONE app.......

Comment: Well, if you find please post as answer to your own question and also in the question I linked above so everyone following these threads know about new Android capabilities.

Comment: Have you seen Android App "Mobile Accesibility UK". This application uses their GUI for incoming and outgoing calls. This is similar to what i want to do. I want to know HOW IS IT POSSIBLE? How can i do it?