# Block incoming calls and sms in android

Tags: android, sms, phone-call, callblocking

I tried to block incoming calls and sms in android for given numbers. after we block a number, when we getting a call from that blocked number, caller can here voice message as **Number Busy**.

But is there any way to change this voice message to **Power off, No service, The number is not in service** messages ?

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible as the carriers are responsible for giving those responses.

Comment: but how carrier give **Number Busy** message in this case? actually number is not busy. but carrier say  Number is Busy. so i think there is a some way to trick carrier and set message as **Power off** or **No service** or **The number is not in service**

Comment: I can see what you are thinking.But i feel u may have to do a lot of tweaking in the android os level to accomplish this.But nice idea though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice thread discussing exactly your question:

[How to block calls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android)

There is a nice explanation link there why it is not possible to do so using `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` but some nice workarounds have been suggested there, worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the message which is returned to the other end depends on how the operator interprets your actions. When you've decided to block a call, regardless on how you do it, you have already received in, and therefore your operator knows that you are *not* powered off, neither off signal. There is nothing you can do on your end.