# How to get blocked number list on Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I know how to [block a call from specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android) but is it possible to retrieve a blocked-contact-numbers list in Android?

Answer (score 2):

In Android 7.0[API Level 24] they introduced [Number Blocking API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#number-blocking) which enables service provider to maintain block number list at Android platform level. It's accessible by default phone app, and carrier apps only. If your app is default messaging app then you can use this API to get the list of all blocked numbers. This is not the exact solution but might be helpful to know.