# Disable contacts button on android dailer app programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app for a child's emergency phone that will allow them to call preprogrammed contacts by pressing a button on the app. The problem is that when it goes into the dialer app the user will have access to the contacts and the other settings available within the dialer. I want to prevent this. Essentially I want to have it so that the only button the child can press is the End Call button which will stop the dialer activity and drop the phone back to my custom home app. Is this possible? Or will I have to replace the entire dialer app (which, it seems, would be less than a trivial solution).

Comment: you can achieve by block the calls look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android

Comment: I'm not so much looking to block the calls, as I can do that at the OS level already with call restrictions. what I'm looking to do is to disable the contacts button so it never opens the contacts activity. when the child presses this button it takes them out of an active call screen to another screen which can confuse a small child. is this possible?