# Detect changes of "Lock SIM card" in Settings/Security/Set up SIM card lock

Tags: android, settings, sim-card

A question aimed at Android 4.0.x preferably.

I want to detect immediately, or after a few seconds, any change made to `Lock SIM card` in `Settings > Security > Set up SIM card lock`.

I tried 3 methods:

1) access read-only `com.android.settings` shared preferences.

```
Context settings = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext("com.android.settings", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences prefSettings = settings.getSharedPreferences("com.android.settings_preferences", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Map<String, ?> allSettings = prefSettings.getAll();
for(String s : allSettings.keySet()){
    //do somthing like String value=allSettings.get(s).toString());
}
```

There is a warning in logcat: "Attempt to read preferences file /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml without permission". The map returned by `getAll()` is empty.

2) `ITelephony.isSimPinEnabled()` always returns false, even when the SIM PIN is enabled and set. So it appears changing the setting has absolutely nothing to do with this interface. I was thinking of polling the interface but this is no good either.

3) creating a `ContentObserver` observing `Settings.Secure` is not working here. Actually, reading the content of `settings.db` with sqlite shows there isn't any record modified when changing this setting. This was also confirmed by the following code:

```
try {
    int lockPattern = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
    // check lock Pattern: 0=disabled, 1=enabled
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // on run, we reach this line.
}
```

The only thing I am sure is that modifying the `SIM PIN enabled` setting rewrites com.android.settings preferences.xml file as shown below:

> $adb shell cat
>   /data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="sim_toggle" value="true" />
<string name="sim_pin"></string>
</map>
```

The tag affected by the change is `sim_toggle`.

Does anyone have an idea? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I got a better shoot at what I am aiming to do: I want to capture internal/telephony/IccCard class event EVENT_CHANGE_FACILITY_LOCK_DONE. Is there a way to do this? It does not seem one of the three registrant lists does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Had to implement a way to finde out if the SimPin is Enabled today.
The ITelephony.isSimPinEnabled() always returned false for me, too. Didn't try the other methods you described.

I found a way to get the current setting:

- First you need to get hold of a proxyPhone Object, how this can be done can be seen here:
  [Can a telephony.Phone object be instantiated through the sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143754/can-a-telephony-phone-object-be-instantiated-through-the-sdk)
- Then you can retrieve the IccCard-Object and on this execute the method getIccLockEnabled.

Code:

```
  Object proxyPhone = PhoneUtil.getProxyPhoneInstance(this);

  Class<?> phone = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.Phone");
  Method getIccCardMethod = phone.getDeclaredMethod("getIccCard");
  Object iccCard = getIccCardMethod.invoke(proxyPhone);
  Class<?> iccCardClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");

  Method getIccLockEnabled = iccCardClass.getDeclaredMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
  Boolean isIccLockEnabled = (Boolean) getIccLockEnabled.invoke(iccCard);
```

works for me on Android 2.3(+?), but as mentioned in the other thread you have to run this code as phone-user/as phone-process.

Really kinda disappointed that there is no public api / deviceAdmin-Api for this. Could imagine that companys want to ensure that their employes keep the sim pin enabled (case of theft).

Comment: I'm going to test your proposal. It seems to match my requirements since I use an external module running in the process com.android.phone. Actually, I already have an ITelephony object in there.

Comment: Is PhoneUtil class still there in Android SDK? I was not able to find any related documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think I have a easy way to detect if a Sim PIN has to be entered. Best of all it's is avaliable via the SDK. You could run this in a [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)...

```
public static boolean isSimPinRequired(){
    TelephonyManager m = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (m.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED) return true;
    return false;
}//end method
```