# Input SIM card PIN automatically after booting

Tags: java, android

I want a way to input a pin code into sim card pin filed after booting,
while Mobile is turned on after logo appears it should ask about the SIM card PIN code I want to type it automatically, how can I do that programmatically for Android devices.

Comment: I hope you can't.

Comment: why ?!! be useful!!

Comment: I think it would be a secuity flaw if the Android system would allow this. It is possible to disable SIM card PIN request, so if the user did not do this, apps (or anything else) should not be able to do this.

Comment: I need this point because I'll publish tablets and want to lock the sim card and I don't want the user know the pin code, I want to input it automatically by an application for security reason

Comment: So your are developing a custom ROM. You could therefore write a system app or a service that performs the PIN entry. However an advanced user could then just extract the PIN from the ROM image.

Comment: @robert I don't care by advanced user I need to prevent it from normal user only

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748638/150978). The class [com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/tools_r22/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccCard.java) looks very promising, especially the `supplyPin()` method.