# How to check the device has set password or not in android?

Tags: java, android, device-admin

In my application, I want to check whether the user has set the password in their android device or not? I tried using device admin apis m not able to get those information. Is there any other way?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322291/how-to-detect-if-pin-code-is-required-to-unlock-sim

Comment: Thanks for your post, m asking for device password.

Comment: Now I got it. Then you'll have to be more specific: on my phone there are password lock, swipe pattern lock, face lock, God knows what else. Which one do you need?

Comment: Awww sorry! I need password lock is set in device or not?

Comment: Anyway, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: I already tried that, we can only set password with complexity, not able to find it out

Comment: This may be made intentionally inaccessible... What do you need this for? Maybe there is some other way to achieve your goal?

Comment: I doing device info app, want to collect those details and send to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Device administrator doesn't allow you to check whether device has lock screen password (or pattern ...) **directly**.

However **you can** do it **indirectly**.

1. [Retrieve](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName%29) password quality level from device admin (original value)
2. [Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) password quality to device admin to minimum level (i.e. PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING)
3. [Ask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isActivePasswordSufficient%28%29) device admin whether is password quality sufficient (if true = user has password)
4. Restore original password quality level (value from step 1)

[DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) allows you to [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29)/[get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName%29) required password quality level and [check](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isActivePasswordSufficient%28%29) whether is password sufficient.

Your device admin will need to use limit-pasword policy:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

And you should definetely read [this Device Administrator Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).