# Developing the security of my App

Tags: android, security, settings

I am trying to make an **Android** app with some security levels, the main of them is that the application needs to check if the mobile phone has the pin blockade active or any other method.
I want to check it at the start of the app, so if the pin blockade  is not turned on the app should be closed down. I dont know how to check it...
In fact, I dont know if this is possible.

Can you access to that settings  of the mobile, from an application?

I mean, if the pin blockade is turned on in the mobile, you get a boolean which value is true, and you could continue with the next screen of the app.
If the boolean is false you cant continue with the next screen until you turn on the pin blockade.

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't really good

Comment: should google before posting. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910698/how-to-check-the-device-has-set-password-or-not-in-android