# Go back to the Android call screen

Tags: android, screen, call

As it seems that you cannot end a call directly from your application, I want to know if there's a way to go back to the android call screen from my application. So the user just have to press a button on my application and be redirected to the android call screen to hang up the call ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can... it's just not easy.

If you have a ITelephony.aidl you can interact with it.

Check this:

[Reflection to access advanced telephony features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001146/reflection-to-access-advanced-telephony-features)

Some other examples in this project:

http://code.google.com/p/teddsdroidtools/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found a workaround using ITelephony, but can I be sure it will work on every Android phone and version ? I think the answer is no... :(

Comment: I think ITelephony works in every phone.. but, there is no guaranty if that's what you mean...

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean :)
But it's working perfectly for the moment !