# Is it possible to Call a android class from java class?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a one android class which extends Activity.

```
 public class MainAct extends Activity{
        Context context;
        SourceJava srcClass;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = this; 
            System.out.println("inside oncreate");
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            srcClass = new SourceJava();
        }
    }
```

I have another Java class as like below and which this is calling from MainAct class.

```
public class SourceJava {       
    public SourceJava(){
        System.out.println("inside constructor***");
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();            
    if(myClass != null){
    System.out.println("**not null");
    myClass.powerOff();

      }

   }       
 }
```

In the SourceJava I am calling another class. i.e

```
 public class MyClass extends Activity{ 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("**inside myclass");
            powerOff();
        }

        public void powerOff(){
            System.out.println("**inside powerOff");
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:5555")); 
            startActivity(call);
        }

    }
  }
```

I am getting NullPointerException on line `startActivity(call)`, 
`myClass.powerOff();` and 
`srcClass = new SourceJava();` 
what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Problem may lie with intent...intent may not be created properly. Try debugging and show log please for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating `MyClass` (which is an Activity class) as regular Java class. The `MyClass` activity is neither registered nor loaded so call to `startActivity` is pointless here. To do so you need to pass reference of `Context` to the `SourceClass` and `MyClass` via constructors.

Comment: I am asking one more question to u. Is it possible access android internal API's. i.e com.android.internal.telephony.

Comment: @shiv1229 - I'd say No. com.android.internal is third party API. Have a look at SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001146/reflection-to-access-advanced-telephony-features and discussion at google - http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b0b8b223a565319f?pli=1

Comment: I posted one more question here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836204/using-android-source-code> I request u to see and plz help me to resolve this problem