# Using Android source code

Tags: java, android

I am developing one application for that I made some changes in CallCard.java class of Phone application.  You can find this class here `<http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/CallCard.java>`. In the above class there are some cases. i.e BUSY, NUMBER_UNREACHABLE and POWER_OFF etc. In the case of POWER_OFF I called a method of a below class.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{ 



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("**inside myclass");

    }

    public  void  powerOff(Context c){
        System.out.println("**inside powerOff");
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:+5555")); 
        startActivity(call);
    }

}
```

This is my own class and added into source directory Phone application. The code is like this:

```
case POWER_OFF:
   resID = R.string.callFailed_powerOff;
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   if(myClass != null){
       System.out.println("**not null");
        myClass.powerOff(getContext);
    }
   break;
```

The reason to do this is, I want to Call other number of same person when first-dialed number is switched_off(currentl hard-coded number). I think this is only one way to this.!! Finaly I started build the code but got some error. i.e  'Cannot find symbol'

```
Symbol: variable getContext
Location: com.android.phone.
    myClass.powerOff(getContext);
                     ^
```

Is my way correct? and why this error. plz help me

Comment: MyClass is my own class in which powerOff method is calling from android source code i.e CallCard.java. u can find that class in a mentioned link. thanks a lot

Comment: My question is - Is MyClass a sub-class of FrameLayout (or any view) or Actrivity?

Comment: actualy CallCard.java is extends FrameLayout. It's not an activity.

Comment: So method call must be myClass.powerOff(getContext()); or myClass.powerOff(this.getContext());

Comment: Is this correct way what I am doing??.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't getContext a method? IMO using `getContext()` should work.
Or, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere), you might want tweak it a bit more.

Comment: IMO should be ok (or as per @nandeesh's variant below). It's just a program :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [getBaseContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) instead of getContext variable