# AT Commands in Android

Tags: android, at-command

I am wondering if someone know what AT Commands are ? i tried to look further on Google but nothing is usefull.

Thank you.

Comment: Really? I typed 'AT commands' into Google, and the first hit was the detailed Wiki article which includes all basic and some advanced AT (Hayes) commands...

Comment: I Said that i don't know what the AT commands is so even if google gave it but with a "Hayes command set" how could i figured it ou that it's talking about AT Commands !?!

Comment: Well, Google does this thing called 'indexing', where they scan web pages and build a dataset which contains phrases or words on that page. So when I typed in 'AT commands' and told Google to search, it scanned its' index looking for pages that contain the term I was looking for. The best match, the Wiki page for Hayes Modem Commands, was ranked as the first result. When I clicked the link, it opened the page, and as I looked at the 'Description' paragraph I read this: "The following text lists part of the Hayes command set (also called the AT commands: "AT" meaning attention).". Seemed legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the Hayes modem control commands? These are the commands used to gain the *AT*tention of a modem and cause it to interact with the phone system and/or computer (to test, read, set and execute commands). A tutorial can be found here: http://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/at-commands

Comment: So, could i interract with the phone by calling the Attention Commands ? is there a way to use that in Android ?

Comment: I'm afraid that's an entirely different question, but it's been asked here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574401/how-to-send-at-command-in-android

Answer (score 1):

[AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) are commands sent to control dial-up modems.

Answer (score 0):

AT commands are the commands given to modem from the application side to get it's **AT**tention and execute commands. Please note that the AT commands may differ from device to device depending upon the manufacturer. 
       And as you have asked specifically for android, so follow the link too know [how to send AT commands to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284067/send-at-commands-to-android-phone).

Don't get confused when you see search results for AT commands but got the results for [Hayes Commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set), the AT commands are part of the Hayes commands.

Also you can find many good resources in the internet for AT commands in general. But again search carefully as the AT commands may differ from device to device.