# Android: toggle 2G and 3G in code with root

Tags: android, toggle, root, 3g

I've read that there is no way to toggle 2g/3g on android in my own code. But is there a solution how to do this with root privileges or smomething like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable 3G/2G in Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170472/how-to-enable-disable-3g-2g-in-android-sdk)

Comment: it's not duplicate, because I'm asking solution with root permissions help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it like this:
(disclaimer: I haven't personally done this, but in theory it can work)

First see this SO question about sending AT commands on Android, especially the 2nd answer about a workaround using root privileges: [How to send AT command in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574401/how-to-send-at-command-in-android).

Then use AT commands to set the device to "2G only or "3G only" or whatever you want.
Using standard AT commands defined in [3GPP 27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm), you can tell the device to select a particular 2G or 3G network (see AT+COPS, AT+CREG).
You can tweak whether you get "2G only" or "2G preferred" by setting the  parameter of the AT+COPS set command to 1 or 4 respectively.

I found 2 ways to do this using different proprietary AT commands.  One is publically available on the internet [here](http://www.kayraelektronik.com/pdf/leon/AT_Commands_Examples_Application_Note_WLS-CS-11003.pdf).  It uses AT+URAT, which as far as I'm aware isn't a standard AT command.

The point here is, that the device probably won't support AT+URAT, but it might have its own proprietary AT command for this function.