# Reject or end a call from the Android API?

Tags: android, call, telephony

Is it possible or not to end or reject a call from the API? I read in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call) that `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` can be used, but Eclipse is returning errors.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that it is from a technical stand point possible. You use the Itelephony class through reflection to basically send the call straight to voicemail. This behaviour is not supported within the public Android APIs however. So even though technically you can make it work, there is no guarantee that it will continue to function as it does now in the future.

Comment: **com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony** returns anyway error