# how to end a incoming call programatically

Tags: android

Hi in my Application i want to hang up the call for the specific number.i have go through many link but can't get any success,here is one of that,in many place a lot of developer told that **com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony** is not working on higher version of android.

[How to hang up outgoing call in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call)

but i found that this Api is available but how to use that.
 http://www.androidjavadoc.com/0.9_beta/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.html

Please help me how to hang up a call.

Comment: http://www.questoid.com/Articles/tabid/190/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/2/Blocking-Incoming-Call.aspx. Here   i got answar.

Comment: Unfortunately that link seems to be dead. Do you still have the code from the solution that you used? Could you post it please?