# android make a miscall from my application

Tags: android, phone-call

i need to make a phone call from my application to some predefined phone number, and after some time interval, lets say 10 seconds after it starts ringing, i want to automatically terminate this call, leaving a miscall. is this possible? 
i used the following code to start the phone call

```
   try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
        }
```

but i have no idea how to stop this particular call.

Comment: Do some google searching for _android telephony manager_.

Answer (score 1):

After initiating the call successfully. you can always use `endCall()` for disconnecting it after your desired interval of time has passed.

Read this thread and search for similar ones on this site:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987399/2021499

Answer (score 1):

First of all,you need to initiate a call and monitor its state and then upon particular time,end the call programmatically .

You already know how to `initiate the call`,I have added a `PhoneStateListener` to `monitor` its state,and I have also added a `code snippet` which describes how to `end call programmatically`.

initiate the call,

```
    private void establishCall()
{
            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) 
              getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tManager .getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT)
    {                   

        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);



            ListenToPhoneState listener = new ListenToPhoneState();
            tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Call failed", e.toString());
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert a Simcard into your device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here is the code of listener,

```
        private class ListenToPhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

        boolean callEnded=false;
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Idle");

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Offhook");
                callEnded=true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Ringing");

        //apply your logic here to wait for few seconds before calling killCall(this) function to end call


                break;


            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

here is the code for ending current call

```
public boolean killCall(Context context) {
try {
   // Get the boring old TelephonyManager
   TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
      (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

   // Get the getITelephony() method
   Class classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
   Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

   // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
   methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

   // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
   Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

   // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
   Class telephonyInterfaceClass =  
       Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
   Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");


       // Invoke endCall()
       methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

   } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
      Logger.e("PhoneStateReceiver **" + ex.toString());
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

inside manifest following permissions will be required,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: hi, thx for the code, i tried it but unfortunately it is not working, the listener  is never fired, have any idea why?

Comment: after debugging i found that the problem is with the state sent to the listener, it is always 0! and onstatechanged is never called when state change to call_state_ringing...