# Android-How to end/disconnect outgoing call

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android. How to hang up outgoing call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call)

Android-How to end/disconnect outgoing call

1-  I  have a receiver and it detects out going calls at there I need to disconnect current call and generate new with different number..

Thanks

Comment: are you making a speed dialer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to disconnect a call handled by the stock phone without using reflection (using code that's not included in the SDK which is not guaranteed to work). It may be possible to intercept the call before it goes through and cancel it but I'm not so clear on that one.